# angular ace editor remove usused mode and snippets js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

I am using ui-ace editor for angular and after installing it through bower I got a folder **ace-builds** which has another folder **src-min-noconflict** which contains a lot of files (200 to be exact) like ext-***, mode-***, theme-***. Also there is another folder in it called **snippets** that which again contains 135 js files.

For my application I need support for javascript, JSON, HTML, XML and CSS. So I dont think keeping all those files is necessary. So are there any files that I can remove like mode-php.js etc foe which I don't need support??

Answer (score 1):

you can remove mode- theme- ext- and worker- files- that you do not use, but these files are not loaded by ace, so you they only take space on server and do not impact the page loading.